Obsidian to anki markdown regex, what does it do?
There is this regex to capture markdown title and content, from Obsidian to anki plugin.
https://github.com/ObsidianToAnki/Obsidian_to_Anki/wiki/Header-paragraph-style
^#+(.+)\n*((?:\n(?:^[^\n#].{0,2}$|^[^\n#].{3}(?<!<!--).*))+)
It works but stops when there is an empty new line.
I've been tinkering with it to see if I could change it so it doesn't stop capturing on an empty line.
Please, can anyone explain what the regex does?
See original
https://regex101.com/r/IotYiZ/2
I've tried removing \n from expresion but messes up with nested titles.
(With X so it's pretty)
    /^\#+(.+)\n*
    (
            (?:\n(?:^[^#].{0,2}$
                 |^[^#].{3}
                      (?<!<!--).*
             )
         )+
     )/gmx


There is a mandatory character here [^#] You might change the pattern to ^#+(.+)((?:\n+(?:^[^\n#]{0,2}$|^(?!<!--)[^\n#]{4}.*))+) https://regex101.com/r/4i0tR0/1

Or ^#+(.+)((?:\n(?!#|<!--).*)+) - https://regex101.com/r/IotYiZ/3

@anubhava Thanks, but I think Wiktor posted a better solution

@WiktorStribiżew You should post an answer for your suggested solution in comments

This regex is strange at most. I'm taking the stop capturing on the first empty line as feature to control what is included.
Still can't understand what this regex does.

If all you want is to find text blocks between lines starting with # and not the one starting with <!--, you can use
^#+(.+)((?:\n(?!#|<!--).*)+)

See this regex demo.
NOTE: If the regex engine does not match CR with ., you can also add \r? before the \n: ^#+(.+)((?:\r?\n(?!#|<!--).*)+).
Details:

^ - start of a string/line (depending on the flag used)
#+ - one or more # chars
(.+) - Group 1: any one or more chars other than line break chars
((?:\r?\n(?!#|<!--).*)+) - Group 2: one or more occurrences of

\r?\n - an optional CR and then an LF char
(?!#|<!--).* - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible not starting with # and <!-- (a line not starting with # and <!--).




Quite simple and working in regex101 capturing almost everything.
Original regex also captures consecutive headers till the text.
Sadly, it does not work in the plugin.
Still can't understand the original regex or whi yours only capture in plugin last ocurrence. Must be something with regex config.

@josem8f Last occurrence only? Does it mean . is set to match newlines, too? Try ^#+([^\n]+)((?:\n(?!#|<!--)[^\n]*)+)

Using your regex only adds as card last title #,##,### etc found. There's no access to regex extra configs. It could be possible to check the code if needed.
